# Search Core Web part with fixed query duedate

Tags: web-part, search-results, query

I have a search core web part and i would like to put there a fixed query, which will search all tasks whose duedate is over, i've added duedate to the columns and it works, but when i try to write fixed query something like that:

```
ContentClass:STS_ListItem_Tasks AND taskstatus:'In Progess' AND duedate > 5/30/2013
```

It doesnt work, says there is an error.

But if i do:

```
ContentClass:STS_ListItem_Tasks AND taskstatus:'In Progess'
```

Then it does, work, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be:

- Make sure you've defined the managed propery duedate
- Don't put spaces in property restriction
- Use standard date format

So the query should be:

```
ContentClass:STS_ListItem_Tasks AND taskstatus:'In Progess' AND duedate>2013-05-30
```

Comment: but when it is rendered, the due date is rendered in the format of 5/30/2013 i think it is default no? as well as xml shows this date format

Comment: That's based on the regional settings of the site, the yyyy-MM-dd format is always supported

Answer (score 0):

If the date is supposed to alwasy be Todays date I think you are out of luck with the OOTB Search Core Results web part. At least for 2010 ,not sure for 2013 but I would guess the same apply there.

[This blog](http://www.martinhatch.com/2012/05/search-core-results-web-part-with.html) provides a lot of code to make a custom one that handles dynamic dates

Otherwise, Anders has the solution for you